# Clicking on an element targeted by id but result is still incorrect

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing Selenium-Webdriver on Google Translate page. What I'm trying to do is:

1. See if the input language is already presented
2. If presented, is it selected? If not select it.
3. If not present, open the more language table. Select (click on) the language on the table.
4. See if the output language is already presented
5. If presented, is it selected? If not select it.
6. If not present, open the more language table. Select (click on) the language on the table.
7. Finally translate and check result

I don't have any problem with Case 1: Input and Output language already presented and the result is as expected. But with Case 2: Output language is not presented yet and has to be selected on the table, the problem occurs. **The language selected is incorrect** (for example, I choose Norwegian but finally Samoan will be selected). *The select input uses the same way to select but doesn't return any issue at all*.

## My code below

```
package TestNG;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class GoogleTranslate {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","F:\\path\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void VietnameseToEnglish() throws InterruptedException { 


    // Go to google translate
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://translate.google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Check if the page is correct
        String currentTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(currentTitle, "Google Translate");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Select Vietnamese as input
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-left']/div[@id='gt-lang-src']/div[@id='gt-sl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='vi']")).size() > 0)
        {
            WebElement Vi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-left']/div[@id='gt-lang-src']/div[@id='gt-sl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='vi']"));
            String isViSelected = Vi.getAttribute("aria-pressed");
            if (isViSelected.equals("false"))
            {
                Vi.click();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WebElement allLangSrc = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-sl-gms"));
            allLangSrc.click();
            WebElement ViSrc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='goog-menuitem-group-7']/div[@id=':2r']/div"));
            ViSrc.click();
        }

    // Select English as output
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-right']/div[@id='gt-lang-tgt']/div[@id='gt-tl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='en']")).size() > 0)
        {

            WebElement En = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-right']/div[@id='gt-lang-tgt']/div[@id='gt-tl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='en']"));
            String isEnSelected = En.getAttribute("aria-pressed");
            if (isEnSelected.equals("false"))
            {
                En.click();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WebElement allLangTrg = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-tl-gms"));
            allLangTrg.click();
            WebElement EnTrg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='goog-menuitem-group-2']/div[@id=':3j']/div"));
            EnTrg.click();
        }

        WebElement Input = driver.findElement(By.id("source-is"));
        //Input.clear();
        Input.sendKeys("Ga");
        WebElement TranslateButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-submit"));
        TranslateButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement Output = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='result_box']/span"));
        String Outtext = Output.getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(Outtext, "Chicken");
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void VietnameseToNorg() throws InterruptedException { 


    // Go to google translate
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://translate.google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Check if the page is correct
        String currentTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(currentTitle, "Google Translate");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Select Vietnamese as input    
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-left']/div[@id='gt-lang-src']/div[@id='gt-sl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='vi']")).size() > 0)
        {
            WebElement Vi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-left']/div[@id='gt-lang-src']/div[@id='gt-sl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='vi']"));
            String isViSelected = Vi.getAttribute("aria-pressed");
            if (isViSelected.equals("false"))
            {
                Vi.click();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WebElement allLangSrc = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-sl-gms"));
            allLangSrc.click();
            WebElement ViSrc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='goog-menuitem-group-7']/div[@id=':2r']/div"));
            ViSrc.click();
        }

    // Select Norg as output
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-right']/div[@id='gt-lang-tgt']/div[@id='gt-tl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='no']")).size() > 0)
        {

            WebElement No = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-lang-right']/div[@id='gt-lang-tgt']/div[@id='gt-tl-sugg']/div[contains(@class,'goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard') and @value='no']"));
            String isNoSelected = No.getAttribute("aria-pressed");
            if (isNoSelected.equals("false"))
            {
                No.click();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WebElement allLangTrg = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-tl-gms"));
            allLangTrg.click();
            WebElement NoTrg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='goog-menuitem-group-5']/div[@id=':52']/div"));
            NoTrg.click();
        }

        WebElement Input = driver.findElement(By.id("source-is"));
        //Input.clear();
        Input.sendKeys("Sua");
        WebElement TranslateButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-submit"));
        TranslateButton.click();    
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement Output = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='result_box']/span"));
        String Outtext = Output.getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(Outtext, "Melk");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){ 
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Off-Topic: You should extract that repeated setup-steps into separate methods, so you can reuse them in your test methods and keep those readable: `public void vietnameseToEnglish() { openGoogleTranslate(); verifyTitle(); selectVietnameseAsInput(); selectEnglishAsOutput(); setInput("Ga"); assertEquals(getOutput(), "Chicken"); }`

Comment: Have you tried [debug your application](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Which branch of your logic is executed?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer I know. But I;m just learning so this one is actually easier for me to debug. I already print the steps and it actually pass the step of clicking on the Language in the table. But I don't see any problem from the web-driver also.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. You should focus on creating functions that do a single thing so that you have reusable code that can be used in various tests easily.

Here are my functions

```
static public String getTranslatedText()
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
    {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d)
        {
            return d.findElement(By.id("result_box")).getText().length() != 0;
        }
    });
    return driver.findElement(By.id("result_box")).getText();
}

static public void setSourceLanguage(String lang)
{
    // see if the desired language is already selected
    if (!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gt-lang-src div.jfk-button-checked")).getText().equals(lang))
    {
        // open the Source language dropdown
        driver.findElement(By.id("gt-sl-gms")).click();

        // select the desired language
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-sl-gms-menu']//div[text()='" + lang + "']")).click();
    }
}

static public void setTargetLanguage(String lang)
{
    // see if the desired language is already selected
    if (!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gt-lang-tgt div.jfk-button-checked")).getText().equals(lang))
    {
        // open the Source language dropdown
        driver.findElement(By.id("gt-tl-gms")).click();

        // select the desired language
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gt-tl-gms-menu']//div[text()='" + lang + "']")).click();
    }
}

static public void translateText(String text)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("source")).sendKeys(text);
}
```

A simple test would look like

```
driver.get("https://translate.google.com/");
setSourceLanguage("English");
setTargetLanguage("Lao");
translateText("This is some text");
System.out.println(getTranslatedText());
```

---

After going through this exercise, I noticed the URL after the text was translated was https://translate.google.com/#en/lo/This%20is%20some%20text. I'm assuming that you aren't testing google translate but instead just want the translations? If that's true, you could just navigate to the URL based on the language tokens and pass in the desired text.

The URL is of the form

```
https://translate.google.com/#<source language token>/<target language token>/<text to be translated>
```

So Vietnamese to English would be

```
https://translate.google.com/#vi/en/This%20is%20some%20text
```

and Vietnamese to Norwegian would be

```
https://translate.google.com/#vi/no/This%20is%20some%20text
```

Then all you would have to do is to grab the translated text.